# Blockchain, smart-contracts and migration

Tags: ethereum

I'm investigating what blockchain technology to use for basically `intercompany asset management` assets like laptops, shares, intellectual property and other, more complex contracts where party X agrees with Y on Z.

Now, `ethereum` looks very suitable but I have a few things that I can't seem to find a clear answer to.

1. What if I create a new `private` blockchain with a genesis file, am I stuck forever with this chain and all its contracts? (i.e. is migrating existing data to another blockchain even possible in any way?)
2. Is the usecase of `where X agrees on Y` doable? Since contracts cannot read eachothers data. How would you translate existing legal documents to a functional or automated entity? I think that third party, centralized servers would be needed in almost any case where the complexity is slightly more that `transfer X value to Y`. Because otherwise contracts are meaningless, other than being registered.

example #1:

When `time X` expires, then invalidate contract Y.

At the very least I would need to externally trigger a new transaction in the blockchain, whenever that time is past?

And in what degree would it be possible to digitalize human-readable contract, albeit simplified versions of it, would one human-contract equate to one `solidity` contract (or LLL or serpent), or would these have to be cut up, and how would they then communicate with eachother?

Comment: You may want to break this up into several questions.  It's hard for any would-be answer-ers to know where to start.  It will also be easier to follow when someone else searches for an answer to one of your questions.

Comment: It's only 2 questions really